# Recursive Algorithm to add consecutive numbers

Tags: recursion

I have the following algorithm that adds t consecutive numbers starting at s.

```
Addup (s,t)
    Make result = s
     For i from s to t-1
          Result = Result + s + i
    Return Result

So Addup (3,3) = 3+4+5 = 12 & Addup (4,5) = 4+5+6+7+8
```

How can this be made recursive?

Q

Comment: I realise the base case will be when t = 1 return s but the recursive call of Addup(s,t-1) needs something more.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, for example:

```
def Addup(s,t):
    if t == 1:
        return s
    else:
        return s + Addup(s+1, t-1)
```